# How to get a \permille perthousand sign in mathjax?

Tags: support, math-display

How to get a `\permille` ("‰", or per thousand) sign in MathJax?  For this post [Binomial GLM and different sample sizes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52206/binomial-glm-and-different-sample-sizes/188834#188834)  I need a `\permille` sign, or `\textperthousand`, but they do not work ...

Comment: Have you considered asking on the [SE TeX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Is that site about mathjax? I thought it was about TeX/LaTeX, not about mathjax?  If you think it is better asked there, I can reask there, and then delete it here.

Comment: I just figured that site would be the natural locus of expertise in this area... .

Comment: According to discussion here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/mathjax-boilerplate  mathjax questions is offtopic there ...  They mention a mathjax tag om SO though ...

Comment: The comments to that question provide some helpful advice and suggestions about where to go for MathJax questions.  I imagine that a carefully formulated MathJax question might be on topic; something like "within the constraints of the MathJax environment, how can I create a facsimile of the unsupported `\textperthousand` character?"

Comment: Historical evidence suggests that would still be considered off topic.  They are willing to answer questions about how you would do something in TeX, but if MathJax doesn't do that, it makes the question off topic.  Better to as on SO or on the [MathJax user forum](http://codepen.io/mathjax/details/avZRzM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would $^0\!\!/\!_{00}$ be close enough?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Glen_b's approach is to use `\unicode{x2030}` ($\unicode{x2030}$), but that relies on the reader having local fonts installed that contain the character, and so may not show up for some, and may produce different results for different people.

Comment: I would prefer a solution which actually works everywhere ...

Comment: Then you will have to go with Glen_b's approach or something similar.  The mathJax fonts do not include the desired character, and so you either have to trust that the user has another font that does, or do something fancy like he suggested.